# Inspect length of array returned by "toHaveLastReturnedWith"

Tags: jestjs

After doing `myfunc = jest.spyOn(...)` for a library method, is there a way to capture the returned value so I can perform `expect()` tests on the returned object? It seems I can only do `expect(myfunc).toHaveLastReturnedWith(...)` but this does not let me acquire what it actually last returned with.

I want to check the length of the arrays, as the contents are dynamic.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to test both caller and callee at the same time, which is a code smell and suggests coupling to implementation details rather than actually having a clean boundary for collaboration. A [mre] would help clarify.

Comment: That's possible. Basically the function under test `f()` calls function `x()` with param p, which determines what `x()` returns. The return is actually a nested array of async funcs with params _p'_.
It looks code smell-y but I'm not sure how else I couldve done it. Will think abt it some more...

Comment: If you're asserting on the array you're testing `f` _and `x`_. If you're testing them together, you shouldn't _also_ be asserting on how they interact. If you're testing them separately, the real `x` shouldn't be involved in the test of `f`, just have a test double that returns an array.

Comment: You're right! I thought testing of f AND x was ... well, parsimony / efficiency. I had never thought about it this way. Thanks for this insight! It means I should have just tested that x was invoked, and then separately tested x in isolation. omg! This is like testing Zen :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
expect(myfunc.mock.results[0].value).toBe(...)
```

So if your mock looked like this:

```
const myfunc = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(['foo', 'bar']
myfunc()
```

Then `myfunc.mock.results[0].value` would return `['foo', 'bar']` and you could check for the value and also possible the length or anything else that you wanna assert.

[Jest Docs: mock-property](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-property:%7E:text=//%20The%20return%20value%20of%20the%20first%20call%20to%20the%20function%20was%20%27return%20value%27%0Aexpect(someMockFunction.mock.results%5B0%5D.value).toBe(%27return%20value%27)%3B)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! It won't work because I don't know what the exact expected result is. I figured out a solution using jest.extend. Thanks!

Comment: Nice that you found a solution. I would guess that it is possible to check for the length of the array in `.value` as well though. You might want to print what `value` contains and go from there.

Comment: Can you add that to your answer so that I can accept it? I think it make more sense than what I ended up doing...